# Is there a way to have confirmed Rabanim?

Tags: feature-request

I know this is a bit hard for several reasons

1. Who would qualify? What type of community? etc.
2. How would they be confirmed?
3. That may take away from this site being a community forum

The benefits however may be worth the effort in the long run

1. They possibly would be able to answer "protected" questions / topics e.g. Psak Halacha , difficult hashkafa questions, etc.
2. There would be some sort of accountability, meaning you would know who the person giving the answer is in real life

some ideas for confirming Rabbis may be if they can verify what shull / school / yeshiva they have a position in, the site can remain inclusive but at the same time we can tag a rabbi as charedi, mizrachi, modern, conservative, etc.

Comment: Related: [Rabbonim on the site](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1615)

Comment: Related: [Anonymity on Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/91/759)

Comment: OK to clarify, i get why there is anonymity, i wanted to know if it is possible for people who want to give that up to choose to do so, and if it is possible to incorporate a verification system. it would be terrible if people impersonated famous Rabbanim...

Comment: i am new to this website but i have been using stackoverflow (stack-exchange for programming ) for several years, so i kind of get how this works

Comment: @IbberChochem [Welcome :)](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/759)

Answer (score 6):

Confirming the identities and external credentials of particular users, granting special status to users and their content based on external credentials, and especially [ascribing independent authority](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1734/can-i-consult-mi-yodeya-as-i-would-a-rabbi) to content posted here are all contrary to the basic Stack Exchange model and Mi Yodeya communal understanding.

Instead, to achieve the two goals you're advocating for, I'd suggest:

1. Mi Yodeya users who want to get and publish answers to difficult questions of Halacha and Hashkafa should pose these questions, offline, to their favorite rabbinic authorities, secure said authorities' permission to quote them in public, and then quote them in answers on Mi Yodeya.
2. Answers should always [cite their sources](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/75/2), whether contemporary or ancient, as precisely and conveniently as possible, making *the information* as accountable as possible to investigation.

Comment: they dont necessarily have to get an advantage over other users. i still think that it would help the people in the community if somebody posting as a rav can be confirmed as such

Comment: @IbberChochem You suggested "They possibly would be able to answer 'protected' questions" which is an advantage.

Comment: I was just throwing out suggestions.  In any case nobody can really answer those questions because they are considered "off topic", BTW for good reason - people should "CYLOR", but if you were to incorporate such a feature this would add a new dimension to this site, which would possibly be a plus. (I personally am not at all qualified to make such a decision if Ravs should answer halacha Qs on a public forum, though my feeling is that ravs would be cautious b4 saying yes) also distinction can be made between General halacha (turning on a light on shabbos) vs complex sheilos like kosher switch

Comment: @IbberChochem Questions are not considered "Off Topic" by virtue of being difficult to answer. Whatever analysis a rabbinic authority could use to support an official decision could just as easily be used by a person with the same information and no authority to post a very valuable answer here. Also, the conclusion of a published ruling by a rabbinic authority  could be cited valuably in an answer here by itself. What's Off Topic is a request for a ruling on the asker's personal situation, which requires not just authority but familiarity with and/or ability to interrogate the asker.