# Can mi yodeya have a live chat feature with rabbis

Tags: feature-request, chat

I’m curious if it is possible for mi yodeya as a site to partner with say a rabbi or posek to create a live chat feature with a Q&A, similar to how Aish.com has, but maybe full time? I hope this proposal doesn’t sound too whacky because I think it would be interesting

Comment: See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8303/reliable-ask-a-rabbi-websites

Comment: Similar https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4522/759

Comment: What's the point? Plenty of these things exist already, what do we have to add?

Comment: I think a live chat feature would be good for people who wanna ask  with a rabbi if they aren’t comfortable posting a question right away @DoubleAA

Comment: They can do that at Aish and other places. Why make another place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in my answer [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4522/is-there-a-way-to-have-confirmed-rabanim), the chief distinguishing value offered by Mi Yodeya is *crowd-sourced* information. We focus on vetting and improving information by subjecting it to scrutiny and editing by a community of interested people, rather than on vetting specific people to provide information authoritatively.

Concretely, if we were to try to implement a feature with a single authoritative answerer, we'd run into challenges like:

- How would we agree on whom to authorize for this purpose?
- How would we find someone whom we have agreed on, who will fill this role?
- How would we convince someone to do this job? Would we compensate them? How?
- How would we hold the answerer accountable for time provided and quality of output?

I do like the idea of adding a less formal, more synchronous feature that does take advantage of our strength as a crowd. We used to hold scheduled, free-form parsha chats in our main chat room. Perhaps scheduled chats, either by text in our chat room or by voice/face using Google Meet or some such, would be a nice thing to bring back.